# How to pass Child Component's form value to Parent Component

Tags: reactjs

Is there a way to pass form data from child component to Parent component, where submit buttons have been kept in parent component.

NOTE: - I don't want to use ref for this as the ref would be waste of so much of memory and I might have 6-7 children in the parent.

I have created a similar situation to show what I am stuck on.

```
class FirstChildForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class SecondChildForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." />
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
            </div>
        );
    }
}



export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                <FirstChildForm />
                <SecondChildForm />

                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Submit</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, the concept is called [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). Basically, your `<App />` component would hold the data from both components. I'm going to simplify a bit, but you should understand what I'm doing.

**FirstChildForm.js**

`<input type="text" name="username" onChange={e => props.updateData('user', e.target.value)}`

**SecondChildForm.js**

`<input type="password" name="password" onChange={e => props.updateData('pass', e.target.value)}`

**App.js**

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            user: '',
            pass: '',
        };
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {};

    updateData = (target, value) => {
        this.setState({ [target]: value });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                <FirstChildForm updateData={this.updateData} />
                <SecondChildForm updateData={this.updateData} />

                <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Submit</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

The `<App />` component is the source of truth. Please note:

By lifting the state up, `<FirstChildForm />` and `<SecondChildForm />` don't need to be class based components anymore, they can be functional components. If you want them to remain class based for whatever reason, change `props.updateData` to `this.props.updateData`, else it won't work.

The parent is where we define the function, the child is where we execute it, sending data to parent, basically!

Comment: Thanks Predrag. I haven't thought of getting form data  on onChange. I was trying to trigger an event in child from parent which takes all form data and then sends that to parent.

Comment: Anytime! Make sure to give the concept some love, as it may cause problems for you as you start building bigger and bigger stuff. Like when you have components nested 6 levels deep, maybe it's time to consider redux!

Answer (score 1):

**by passing a function to the child component as props and passing the child component's state as parameter to the function**

as i dont know what you exactly want to code inside but only to understand checkout

**following example**

parent:

```
    export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }


    handleSubmit = () => {

  }  
  handleData = (newData) => {
    this.setState({data: newData});
}

render(){
  return (
  <div className="parent">
  <FirstChildForm / >
  <SecondChildForm  onSelectData={this.handleData}/>

  <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}> Submit</button>
  </div>
  )
}
}
```

Child:

```
 class SecondChildForm extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data:'hello'
    }
  }

  handleDataChange: function () {
    var newData = this.state.data
    this.props.onSelectData(newData);            
},

render(){
  return (
  <div className="form">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." />
  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" />
  <button onclick={this.handleDataChange}>submit</button>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to pass a function down to your children components. Your children will now be able to bind this function from their props to the given fields.

```
class FirstChildForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." onChange={this.props.dataChanged('name')}/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" onChange={this.props.dataChanged('password')}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


class SecondChildForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name..." onChange={this.props.dataChanged('name')}/>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" onChange={this.props.dataChanged('password')}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        }
    }

    handleChange = form => field => ev => {
        this.setState(prev => ({ [form]: { ...prev[form], [field]: ev.target.value } }))
    }
```

The resulting state of your parent will have the following structure :

```
{
    'firstForm': {
        'name': '',
        'password': ''
    },
    'secondForm': {
        'name': '',
        'password': ''
    }
}
```